How can we tell how similar two countries look on a map?
Suppose I have these 2 maps:

I can represent these two maps in matrix form:
map1 <- matrix(
  c("R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "B",
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "B",
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "B", "B", "B",
    "R", "R", "R", "R", "R", "P", "R", "B", "B", "B",
    "R", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "B", "B", "B",
    "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "B", "B", "B",
    "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y",
    "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y", "Y",
    "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y",
    "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
  nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE
)

map2 <- matrix(
  c("R", "R", "R", "P", "P", "P", "B", "B", "B", "B",
    "R", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "B", "B",
    "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "B",
    "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P",
    "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P",
    "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y",
    "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y",
    "G", "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y", "Y",
    "G", "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y",
    "G", "G", "G", "P", "P", "P", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"),
  nrow = 10, byrow = TRUE
)

Map 1:

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] R    R    R    R    R    R    R    B    B    B    
 [2,] R    R    R    R    R    R    R    B    B    B    
 [3,] R    R    R    R    R    R    R    B    B    B    
 [4,] R    R    R    R    R    P    R    B    B    B    
 [5,] R    P    P    P    P    P    P    B    B    B    
 [6,] P    P    P    P    P    P    P    B    B    B    
 [7,] G    G    P    P    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    
 [8,] G    G    P    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    Y    
 [9,] G    G    P    P    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    
[10,] G    P    P    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    Y    


Map 2:

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] R    R    R    P    P    P    B    B    B    B    
 [2,] R    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    B    B    
 [3,] P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    B    
 [4,] G    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    
 [5,] G    G    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    
 [6,] G    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    P    Y    
 [7,] G    G    P    P    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    
 [8,] G    G    G    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    Y    
 [9,] G    G    G    P    P    P    P    P    Y    Y    
[10,] G    G    G    P    P    P    Y    Y    Y    Y   

I wrote this function to convert both of these into shapefiles:
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)



matrix_to_polygons <- function(matrix_data, cell_size = 1) {
  # Create empty lists to store polygons and their attributes
  polygons_list <- list()
  values_list <- character()
  counter <- 1
  
  for(i in 1:nrow(matrix_data)) {
    for(j in 1:ncol(matrix_data)) {
      xmin <- (j - 1) * cell_size
      xmax <- j * cell_size
      ymin <- (nrow(matrix_data) - i) * cell_size  
      ymax <- (nrow(matrix_data) - i + 1) * cell_size
      
      coords <- matrix(c(
        xmin, ymin,
        xmax, ymin,
        xmax, ymax,
        xmin, ymax,
        xmin, ymin
      ), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
      
      polygon <- st_polygon(list(coords))
      
      polygons_list[[counter]] <- polygon
      values_list[counter] <- matrix_data[i, j]
      
      counter <- counter + 1
    }
  }
  
  sf_object <- st_sf(
    value = values_list,
    geometry = st_sfc(polygons_list, crs = 3857)
  )
  
  sf_dissolved <- sf_object %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry))
  
  return(sf_dissolved)
}

map1_sf <- matrix_to_polygons(map1)
map2_sf <- matrix_to_polygons(map2)

plot(map1_sf["value"], main = "Map 1")
plot(map2_sf["value"], main = "Map 2")

The results now look like this:
> map1_sf
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  value                                                                 geometry
  <chr>                                                            <POLYGON [m]>
1 B     ((7 7, 7 8, 7 9, 7 10, 8 10, 9 10, 10 10, 10 9, 10 8, 10 7, 10 6, 10 5,…
2 G          ((0 0, 0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 0 4, 1 4, 2 4, 2 3, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1, 1 0, 0 0))
3 P     ((2 3, 2 4, 1 4, 0 4, 0 5, 1 5, 1 6, 2 6, 3 6, 4 6, 5 6, 5 7, 6 7, 6 6,…
4 R     ((0 7, 0 8, 0 9, 0 10, 1 10, 2 10, 3 10, 4 10, 5 10, 6 10, 7 10, 7 9, 7…
5 Y     ((8 1, 8 2, 7 2, 7 3, 8 3, 8 4, 9 4, 10 4, 10 3, 10 2, 10 1, 10 0, 9 0,…
> map2_sf
Simple feature collection with 5 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 0 xmax: 10 ymax: 10
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  value                                                                 geometry
  <chr>                                                            <POLYGON [m]>
1 B     ((9 7, 9 8, 8 8, 8 9, 7 9, 6 9, 6 10, 7 10, 8 10, 9 10, 10 10, 10 9, 10…
2 G     ((0 1, 0 2, 0 3, 0 4, 0 5, 0 6, 0 7, 1 7, 1 6, 2 6, 2 5, 1 5, 1 4, 2 4,…
3 P     ((3 3, 2 3, 2 4, 1 4, 1 5, 2 5, 2 6, 1 6, 1 7, 0 7, 0 8, 1 8, 1 9, 2 9,…
4 R                ((0 8, 0 9, 0 10, 1 10, 2 10, 3 10, 3 9, 2 9, 1 9, 1 8, 0 8))
5 Y     ((7 1, 8 1, 8 2, 7 2, 7 3, 8 3, 8 4, 9 4, 9 5, 10 5, 10 4, 10 3, 10 2, …


Here is my question: Are there any methods in geography/geospatial to measure how similar the shape of the purple blob in map1 is compared to the shape of the purple blob in map2?
For example, country 1 is 100 km2 in the shape of a triangle , country 2 is 10km2 in the shape of a triangle, country3 is 99 km2 in the shape of a circle. I am interested in learning about different metrics that compares these countries by shape (metric 1) vs shape and area (metric 2).
After doing some reading, I thought we could use the Jaccard Index (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for this?
map1_purple <- map1_sf %>% filter(value == "P")
map2_purple <- map2_sf %>% filter(value == "P")

intersection <- st_intersection(map1_purple, map2_purple)
union <- st_union(map1_purple, map2_purple)

jaccard_similarity <- st_area(intersection) / st_area(union)

This makes it looks like they are 43% similar:
> jaccard_similarity 
0.4347826 [1]

Is there some standard metric that can do these types of comparisons?

A naive comparison for the full map:

# method 1
matches <- 0
total <- 100  

for(i in 1:10) {
  for(j in 1:10) {
    if(map1[i,j] == map2[i,j]) {
      matches <- matches + 1
    }
  }
}

similarity <- (matches/total) * 100

# method 2
mean(map1 == map2) * 100


Try hausdorff distance in scipy, but you need to bring 2nd shape to overlap the 1st. I'd use scipy minimize 3 parameters- x,y and rotation

thanks for the feedback Felix ... I updated my question to show what I tried

Do you only care about shape, or is location and size important too? Its just that "shape similarity" in computer science is often location-invariant, for example in computer vision when the goal is to find an object that looks like another object.

@Spacedman : Is there some measure that balances both of these? For example, suppose there is some land shared by 5 people and each person has their territory. These 5 people have a war and the territories shapes, locations and sizes are redistributed. How do tell how similar the before/after maps look?

There are several approaches to measure the similarity, you can compare the area, distances between vertexes/lines, for introduction see for example https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/362644/199931. You may use turning function https://doi.org/10.1109/34.75509 and https://github.com/DBraun/turning-function/tree/main. In R you can calculate the Hausdorff distance with {sf} sf::st_distance(which = "Hausdorff").

First you could  remove scale, orientation and placement issues by using a minimum bounding box and affine transforming the result to a common box. Then I would suggest a simple confusion matrix (CM)
https://ecampusontario.pressbooks.pub/remotesensing/chapter/chapter-7-accuracy-assessment/
CM will only tell you how many cells are the same class between the two vs how many are different, but if you then create some dummy layers with archetypal geometric shapes in various sizes and run the CM against each of these also, you can cluster the resulting similarities for each "shaped like a..." dimension.  Defining the right dummy layers might be the hard part.
